# How to set the lambda if the properties won't be known until runtime?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a generic method that I can use anywhere within my application.

Here is my method:

```
public T GetEntry(ObjectId id)
{
    IMongoCollection<T> collections = db.GetCollection<T>(database);
    var getObj = collections.Find( ).FirstOrDefault();      // something like x => x.id == id
    return getObj;
}
```

`Find` takes a lambda expression that will specify the constraints but I can't set it because the properties won't be known until runtime. How do I set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Interface for this solution

```
public Interface IEntity
{
    int Id {set ;get}
}


class EntryManagement<T> where T : IEntity
{
    public T GetEntry(ObjectId id)
    {
        IMongoCollection<T> collections = db.GetCollection<T>(database);
        var getObj = collections.Find(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();      
        return getObj;
     }
}
```

or you can create your lambda expression dynamically at runtime

```
public T GetEntry(ObjectId id)
{
    IMongoCollection<T> collections = db.GetCollection<T>(database);
    var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "object");
    var propertyOrFieldExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, "Id");
    var equalityExpression = Expression.Equal(propertyOrFieldExpression, Expression.Constant(id, typeof(int)));
    var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equalityExpression, parameterExpression);

    var getObj = collections.Find(lambdaExpression).FirstOrDefault();
    return getObj;
}
```

Comment: Alright, I tried your second solution and It worked!! I just have to change it to `typeof(ObjectId)` since It's `ObjectId` and not `int`. Just a question though. If i will use your first solution, do i need to implement `IEntity` for all my model classes?

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta yes, I forget to mention that , for the first solution all of your model classes have to implement IEntity. I myself prefer the first solution because it's hard type.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to change the search expression at the caller? In that case it's probably easiest to just pass in the expression from the caller. Something like this:

```
public T GetEntry<T>(ObjectId id, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    IMongoCollection<T> collections = db.GetCollection<T>(database);
    var getObj = collections.Find(predicate).FirstOrDefault(); // Call passed in predicate
    return getObj;
}
```

Then when you call the function you can do something like:

```
var person = GetEntry<Person>(id, person => person.Id == id);
```